# How to make navbar a bullet list

Tags: bootstrap-4

Q: Is there a way to have a bullet separating each nav-item?
My users have large screens so I'm not concerned about what happens to the collapse menu. When running this snippet, make sure you use full page.

If it helps, I am using fontawesome as well. If you want to use the fa-ul class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu A <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu B</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu C</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Menu D</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
.nav-link::before {
  content: "•";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. that's nice. How do you get unicode characters into your copy/paste buffer?

Comment: I just highlight the actual entity from this list: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp

Comment: I can use "\2022" instead of the entity.

Comment: or since you are using font-awesome you can put in the unicode for any of those icons ex. "\f111"